# PDF Page view tracking

Tags: php, jquery, google-analytics, google-ads-api, google-tag-manager

Can anybody know how we can track pdf page views, open or not.
e.g. suppose `pdf` has 10 pages then I want to track out of 10 pages which is most readable and least readable page from the marketing point of view.

I don't want download tracking.
Is it possible using google tag manager? if yes, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using something like [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), then it could be possible, sure. But standard PDFs that users download? No.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can with [Orangedox](http://orangedox.com/pdf) for Business, it'll give you the time the PDF was viewed as well as the time spent on each page of the PDF. And was actually made with content marketers in mind.

Here's an article that should explain a little bit more

[How to Track PDF Viewership](https://hub.orangedox.com/home/tracking-pdf-page-viewership.docx)

Disclaimer: I work for Orangedox